# Exporting the fact that a push notification has been opened

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobilepush

I've successfully built a journey that will send a push notification when the user installs the iOS app I am working on.

We then use Update Contact to export some data using Data extensions.

How / where do I query in Sales Force Marketing cloud to see if the push notification was opened?